# Сreate an object of type T from another object that implements type T

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
type T = {
    a: number
    b: string
}

class SomeClass implements T {
    a: number = 1
    b: string= ''
    
    c: boolean = false
}

let object1: SomeClass = new SomeClass()
let object2: T = ???
```

How can I get a new object from an instance of SomeClass that contains only properties of type T (a,b), without any other SomeClass properties (c)?

Comment: What's wrong with `let object2: T = {a: object1.a, b: object1.b}`? I'm not sure what this question is really asking.

Comment: @lawrence-witt: The issue is `get a new object from an instance of SomeClass`, not the typing.

Answer (score 3):

Types do not exist at runtime, so you cannot use them for processing an instance. There are various ways in which this could be approached, e.g. if `T` were a class, possibly its [metadata could be emitted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata) and used at runtime to transform the object.

You could also define a function where you pass in the keys and the type system will ensure that only valid keys are used. But making sure that all keys are present is another issue.

```
function limitProperties<T extends K, K>(
  instance: T,
  ...keys: (keyof K)[]
) {
  // Naive shallow implementation
  const obj = {} as any as K;
  for (const key of keys)
    obj[key] = instance[key]

  return obj;
}

let object1: SomeClass = new SomeClass()
let object2: T = limitProperties(object1, 'a', 'b'); // Adding 'c' causes error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeAoK6oEMBcUB2ArgLYBGEATmhibgM7DkCWeA5igL4ooDGANprVpQAygHsiEAML9BURkTC8IEvMCFxUGLLkKkKCKAEYq6GlHpNWiAOTWTUe91wlRopZjwGAZpl60IHFxeBHjcwIyinrzyjMAACuSikOThELQAPHAQAB7AEHgAJkIA0gA0UMUAfAAUVMz0HtwQuDClVAB0nQDWECC0uNU9IKJeFQCUANoAuihjyFTckfRQoiQAVgZI7FhCHiA7FQDcVF6i5FDVi3jLQyujQ7Rj9qtrE0NTBvXAjRBvvTNUcgQYAEcieF7HTgoJTAFbrCBhQy4MQSaQCISIPAQADuInEUhktGqTxhcLWCOAACYWgZokRYgkkhRUkSXhTDOVrJhrJySNYxsceEs3BB2rxRCxqmywpSxkA)

There also are libraries which usually are used for request validation that can help with this. E.g. with [Zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod):

```
import { z } from 'zod';

const t = z.object({
  a: z.number(),
  b: z.string(),
});

type T = z.infer<typeof t>; // Original T derived from object

class SomeClass implements T {
    a: number = 1
    b: string= ''
    
    c: boolean = false
}

let object1: SomeClass = new SomeClass()
let object2: T = t.parse(object1);
```

[Playground (not runnable)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=20&ssc=22&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgNwBQFAxhAHYDO88AvCgHQQBGAVgKbUYACgQU4cAIYAuDnQCuILnyhCAlABoxcLjOTsmUYHQDmazWlWUKMAJ5g%20cACpw2eo5mUAeW-YiY4MAB8VtQANhIMDHAAyrh8AMLhkXCgYKF8IHx0MFHOouLi0nDyisoucACMWuI6cAZGxmz4%20NVwrdQyXBAQ6RJ05ZgSoQx8FGhU6fDc-IIVMrGZiRFRbHR8AO4xcUuRahSTcNMCMABMMs5sMOxgElAjQkezllS0jD187KEQpo%20nz0A)

Answer (score 1):

It's called **Excess Property Checks** which TypeScript does not trigger by default, the base behavior for most interfaces is to see the structure as type contracts or a generic, which only requires partial match.

Although there are certain syntaxes that triggers exact match. It's not being a common paradigm so I would suggest you to not think of things this way (by exact matching) when first getting started.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks

Comment: My problem arose, because the object of type T will be converted to JSON, so there  need to exclude redundant properties. Can you advise something to solve this problem?

Comment: @AlexandrKat Since you're probably using this JSON data as part of the exported file or API response. I would suggest you to add a public data mapper function to the class. Or implement another helper for dealing with this.

The definition of Class is meant to be a living object. Which would mixed with a lot of additional properties (like those you extended from). 

So you might be better off having a separate layer of data mapping, or just not use classes in the first place.